# How to manipulate LikeBy, NoOfLikes, RatedBy, AverageRating, UserRating using CSOM

Tags: csom, rating, spfielduser

I want `SPFieldUserValueCollection` in CSOM. How do I and manipulate it? In particular, how to manipulate `LikeBy`, `NoOfLikes`, `RatedBy`, `AverageRating`, `UserRating` all using strictly CSOM.

Comment: Can you be more descriptive about your question regarding manipulation of rating

Comment: Manipulation here is to able to add a user into `LikeBy` field or increment the value of the `NoOfLikes` field or recalculating the value of the `AverageRating` field when a new rating is added using the formula `NewAverage`=(`OldAverage`*`OldNoOfRatings`+`NewRating`)/`NewNoOfRatings` where `NewNoOfRating` (is obviously)= `OldNoOfRating`+1. etc. @Unnie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gone through the problem an got the relevant answer also made blog on it so visit the [blog post](http://ashwinkheta.blogspot.in/2016/10/sharepoint-2013-csom-star-ratings.html)

Some of the important aspects covered are described breifly as follows.

To rate an Item for the first time by a user the following fields should be modified with the respective field values:

> 1. `item["RatingCount"]`:
>
>    > This field stores the number of users who have rated the item its value should be incremented.
> 2. `item["Ratings"]`:
>
>    > A field which stores the user ratings in CSV string format should add the new users rating like.
>    >
>    > ```
>    > int NewRating = 4; //any desired number from 1 to 5.
>    > item["Ratings"] += NewRating + ",";
>    > ```
> 3. `item["AverageRating"]`:
>
>    > This field stores the average of the ratings given by all the rated users. Simple weighted average calculation formulas can be implemented which is
>    >
>    > ```
>    > float OldAverage = item["AverageRating"] == null ? 0 : float.Parse(item["AverageRating"].ToString());
>    > int OldNumberOfRatings = item["RatingCount"] == null ? 0 : int.Parse(item["RatingCount"].ToString());
>    > int NewNumberOfRatings = OldNumberOfRatings + 1;  
>    >
>    > float NewAverage = OldAverage + ( ( NewRating - OldAverage ) / NewNumberOfRatings);
>    > //Or.
>    > float NewAverage = ( ( OldAverage * OldNumberOfRatings ) + NewRating ) / NewNumberOfRatings;
>    >
>    > item["AverageRating"] = NewAverage;
>    > ```
> 4. `item["RatedBy"]`:
>
>    > This field stores the user information in form of array of `FieldUserValue` which can be modified using following code
>    >
>    > ```
>    > FieldUserValue[] ratedUsers = item["RatedBy"] as FieldUserValue[];
>    > //where ratedUsers becomes an array of users who have already rated.
>    > List<FieldUserValue> newUsersRated = new List<FieldUserValue>();
>    > if (ratedUsers != null)
>    >     foreach (FieldUserValue ratedUser in ratedUsers)
>    >         newUsersRated.Add(ratedUser);
>    > newUsersRated.Add(FieldUserValue.FromUser(user.LoginName));
>    > item["RatedBy"] = newUsersRated;
>    > ```

To Rerate the item for a user who has already rated it before you need to first find the user index (say `int userIndex`) in the `item["RatedBy"]` field then change the following fields:

> 1. `item["Ratings"]`:
>
>    > Change the user rating in this CSV string by use of `userIndex`.
>    >
>    > ```
>    > FieldUserValue[] ratedUsers = item["RatedBy"] as FieldUserValue[];
>    > for (int i = 0; i < ratedUsers.Length; i++)
>    >     if (ratedUsers[i].LookupValue == user.Title)
>    >         int userIndex = i;
>    > string[] userRatings = item["Ratings"].split(',');
>    > int OldRating = int.Parse(userRatings[userIndex]);
>    > int NewRating = 3; //any desired number from 1 to 5.
>    > userRatings[userIndex] = NewRating.ToString();
>    > string ratings = userRatings.Join(',', userRatings);
>    > item["Ratings"] = ratings;
>    > ```
> 2. `item["AverageRating"]`:
>
>    > change the average value using formula
>    >
>    > ```
>    > float OldAverage = item["AverageRating"];
>    > int NumberOfRatings = item["RatingCount"];
>    > float NewAverage = OldAverage + ( ( NewRating - OldRating ) / NumberOfRatings );
>    > item["AverageRating"] = NewAverage;
>    > ```
>
> No need to change the values in `item["RatingCount"]` and `item["RatedBy"]` fields.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: made changes as suggested